# In latest visual studio code 1.37.1 and the latest pytest==5.1.1, all test passed but I've got an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytest

I've got an error when testing my code in vscode using pytest, it says:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined
```

All tests passed and
I've updated pytest, my python extension in vscode.It is still not working.

This is one of my tests:

```
def test_3():
    i = 0
    while i < 30:
        assert fibo_correct(i) == fibo(i)
        i += 1
```

The function fibo_correct():

```
def fibo_correct(n):
    return 1 if n <= 2 else fibo_correct(n - 1) + fibo_correct(n - 2)
```

The function fibo():

```
def fibo(n):
    a = []
    a.append(1)
    a.append(1)
    for i in range(2, n):
        a.append(a[i - 1] + a[i - 2])
    return a[n - 1]
```

I tried [use pytest==5.0.1 instead of 5.1.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6990)
and it works well. But why?

Comment: Ask the question in the github issue. This is not the correct place to ask.

Comment: There should be a line number and file name describing the location so please also post that, but this sounds like a bug in VS Code to me as that's a JavaScript error.

Comment: OK, I'll  also ask the question in the github issue. @drum

Comment: Yes, they said there was an issue in the python extension in vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and stumbled upon this SO question. I tried to find appropriate links to GitHub projects and add them here. Only after did I notice the link at the end of the original question.

The issue opened in [VSCode project](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79299) says the problem is in the Python extension.

The issue opened in
[Python-extension project](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6990) currently advices to downgrade pytest to version 5.0.1. The problem seems to be with pytest version 5.1.0.

Until the problem is fixed well have to resort to using an older version of pytest.